# How can I resolve the 'TypeError: 'list' object is not callable' error in this threaded pyside code that seems to work fine in a similar case?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside, qthread

The full traceback for my error is:

> > python zthreadtest_tjedit.py
>
> None
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "zthreadtest_tjedit.py", line 17, in run self.function()
>
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

I apologize that's this code is a bit system specific and probably won't serve as an executable example for most people.  Hopefully the solution is simple enough for someone to see right off. If you're not running zfs with a currently imported zpool, but are on a *nix platform with the weir.zfs module installed, it will return an empty list with the non-threaded code enabled (see comments in code for toggling threading). With the threading module enabled, it throws the error as shown above.

Confusing to me is that the second snip of code from Jo Plaete (https://joplaete.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/threading-with-pyqt4/) runs without error, and I simply modified this code to my needs.
EDIT: This error-causing difference may be related to the list object used in my code and not hers, but I still need to make mine work.

My question is: how do I resolve my error such that my threaded module runs correctly?

This seems simple, but I'm absolutely stumped.  So much so that this is the first question I've posted on any help forum ever!  I hope I've asked my question properly and I appreciate any help.

**My Code, from much larger pyside gui program:**

```
import PySide, sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import re, subprocess, threading
from weir import zfs

class WorkerThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, function):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.function = function

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        self.function()
        return


class MainZ(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainZ, self).__init__()
        # print(self)
        # imported_pools = self.get_imported() # No threading
        imported_pools = self.thread_test()  # Use threading module

        print(imported_pools)

    def thread_test(self):
        self.threader = WorkerThread(self.get_imported())
        self.threader.start()

    def get_imported(self):
        pool_string = subprocess.getoutput(
            'zpool list |grep -v ^NAME.*SIZE.*ALLOC |grep -o ^[a-Z0-9]*')
        imported_pools = re.split(r'\s *', pool_string)
        return imported_pools


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainZ()
app.exec_()
```

**Code I modeled from Jo Plaete that works for me without error:**

```
import sys, time
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class GenericThread(QtCore.QThread):
 def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
  QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
  self.function = function
  self.args = args
  self.kwargs = kwargs

 def __del__(self):
  self.wait()

 def run(self):
  self.function(*self.args,**self.kwargs)
  return

class MyApp(QtGui.QWidget):
 def __init__(self, parent=None):
  QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
  self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 600)
  self.setWindowTitle('threads')
  self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
  self.testButton = QtGui.QPushButton("test")
  self.connect(self.testButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("released()"), self.test)
  self.listwidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
  self.layout.addWidget(self.testButton)
  self.layout.addWidget(self.listwidget)

 def add(self, text):
  """ Add item to list widget """
  print("Add: " + text)
  self.listwidget.addItem(text)
  self.listwidget.sortItems()

 def addBatch(self,text="test",iters= 5,delay=0.2):
  """ Add several items to list widget """
  for i in range(iters):
   time.sleep(delay) # artificial time delay
   self.add(text+" "+str(i))

 def test(self):
  self.listwidget.clear()
  self.genericThread = GenericThread(
   self.addBatch,"from generic thread ",delay=0.3)
  self.genericThread.start()


# run
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
test = MyApp()
test.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: The traceback that you did not copy and paste here has at least part of the answer.

Comment: I hope my edit is what you were referring to.  Nothing in there had enlightened me right off but I'm going through it again given your lead...

Comment: Still just not getting it.  I've implemented a similar mini-program successfully using Plaete's 'GenericThread' class above (I won't pollute the post with more working code), but any part of my main program that I try to call that way gives the stated error.  There's just some difference I'm just not getting here.

Comment: I expected the failing call to be something else.  WorkerThread.__init__` should be called with `self` equal to the result of `WorkerThread.__new__`, which is the inherited `QThread.__new__`.   `None` should not be possible.  I would add `print(self)` before the call.  Also, since you subclassed `QThread`, I would call `QThread.__init__` rather than `QtCore.QThread.__init__`.  This seems 'dumb' as these should be the same, but when debugging something that seems 'impossible', eliminating other 'impossibles' sometimes helps me.

Comment: Did you try adding the `*args` and `**kwargs` to your `__init__` signature?  Qt has some weird stuff where it maps Python methods to overloaded C++ methods based on their signature, so sometimes that kind of difference can cause a problem.

Comment: I ran the code, and it does not produce that error. I obviously had to replace the body of the `get_imported` function with a `QThread.sleep()` to test it - but your traceback shows it never gets as far as calling that function, so it doesn't seem relevant. Are you *absolutely sure* that the code in your question really produces that error? Because I'm not seeing how it ever could.

Comment: PS: please also state how you are running this code. Are you using some kind of IDE or debugger?

Comment: PPS: That `builtins.TypeError` looks *really* suspicious - why is `builtins` specified? This looks like an issue with how you're running the script, rather than with the script itself.

Comment: BrenBarn: Yes, I started out with that and, right or not, trimmed things down for simplicity and nothing changed.

Comment: Terry:  I'm working through what you've suggested, will take a bit to process. Thx, will update.

Comment: ekhumoro: Interesting.  I will try first executing the code from command line then replacing zstuf with sleep as I prob should have done for the example in the first place.  I am running my code from Wing IDE.  Thx.

Comment: Traceback from Eric and command line read a bit differently than what I posted from Wing IDE. Eric: The debugged program raised the exception unhandled TypeError "'list' object is not callable" File: /home/bill/Devel/python/z4me/bez/zthreadtest.py, Line: 17             and command line gives: [root@arch1 bez]# ppp zthreadtest.py 
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zthreadtest.py", line 17, in run
    self.function()
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
then hangs. Still working on other suggestions as I stated above and will update again.

Comment: Oh, it has to do with my list?  That's what the other (Eric and command line) traces imply and ekhumoro didn't get an error when he replaced the list-containing code with a timer.  I don't know what this means right off.

Comment: @airhuff. Please run the script in an ordinary console. Do not use an IDE or debugger of any kind to test example code that you post on SO, unless your question is specifically about those coding environments.

Comment: @ekhumoro. Thx for the info, will do.  Does the console traceback give you any ideas?  oops, dang it, I used my shortcut for the python3 command, ppp.

Comment: @airhuff. Please edit your question and paste the full traceback you see in the console. And also ensure that the code example still matches the script you are currently running.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy. I made your changes and get the same traceback as above (running everything from console now).  The output of print(self) is <__main__.MainZ object at 0x7f78cd819a08>

Comment: @ekhumoro.  Good idea, will do shortly. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
    self.threader = WorkerThread(self.get_imported())
```

should read

```
    self.threader = WorkerThread(self.get_imported)
```

When creating the thread, you want to pass the function itself and not the result of calling the function (which is a list).

Comment: Thx @NPE.  I had tried this and thought it was giving me the same error, but I've realized it was just a quirk of my IDE debugger.  When run from the command line the code as you have it just prints 'None' then hangs until I hit control z.  If I don't run it through the threading bit it prints out the imported pools as it should.

Comment: @airhuff Your code is not written to print the result of the function the worker thread executes. Your code prints the result of the function which creates the worker thread.

Comment: @NPE, great progress.  Putting the print statement in the right place gets it to print my imported pools.  Do you see a reason why it would continue to hang though?  It won't exit until I ctrl-z out.

Comment: @airhuff. It's not hanging. You started an event-loop, which will just sit there waiting for events until you explicitly stop it. For example, if you showed the window, closing it would also quit the application.

Comment: @NPE.  Of course, don't know what I was thinking.  Just got flustered with it all.  To top it off, my IDE is completely flaky on this and prob needs a bug report.  I can run my prog several times in a row with all working fine(manually stopping it each time) then out of the blue the debugger will throw this odd 'self can't be None' error a few times then work again.  No code change. No rapid-fire run-stop cycling.  Just has to be a bug.  Anyway, thanks so much for your help, this had me pulling my hair out. Cheers, airhuff.